# Reading data using spring JPA + PostgreSql stored Procedure based on cursor

Tags: java, postgresql, cursor, spring-data-jpa

I need to read the data from a table having a condition until to reach the needed amount of data using a Cursor based Stored Procedure in PostgreSql.

I do not know how can I make a call from Spring JPA to this type of procedure! 
I am wondering if I should make a loop in the Stored Procedure until I reach the maximum of rows I want and then just call the stored Procedure once or should I call the Stored Procedure in Spring JPA several times until reaching the maximum rows?

I appreciate your suggestions and examples.

Comment: Your proc can return a `refcursor`, which PgJDBC will automatically translate into a result set accessible with `getMoreResults()` on the `Statement` object

Comment: @CraigRinger So I should call getMoreResults() on the statement until I reach the required  amount of data. Something like this: while (condition is true) {statement.getResultSet(); statement.getMoreResults()}; The question is when I call getMoreResults() it makes another call to DB?

Comment: no, not like that. See the API documentation. You might not even need getMoreResults if you return refcursor not setof refcursor. The point is that getMoreResults is how you access multiple result sets. Write a test program to see how PgJDBC handles the refcursor return.